# using nav msg map in UI

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developoing a mission planner where nav_msgs/MapMeta data has been loaded into ui. Here i am trying to display the position of robot in given map with (x,y) coordinates. The map.yaml is as:

```
image: nic_map4.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-51.224998, -51.224998, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

Here for example if the robot position is comming as (1,1) a set the robot pose as x=1*resolution, y=1*resolution but the positions seems not correct. How exactly should i display the position of robot in given map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382968/using-nav-msg-map-in-ui/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2021-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The origin of the map.yaml [-51.224998, -51.224998, 0.000000] refers to the position of the bottom left corner pixel of your map image with respect to your map frame. So, in order to represent your robot's position at (1,1) [with respect to the map frame], your pixel value from the **bottom left corner of the map image** would be: [1044.49996 pixels,1044.49996 pixels]

**Calculation**:

pixel value of the map origin in x: +51.224998 / resolution = +51.224998 / 0.05 = 1024.49996 pixels

pixel value of the map origin in y: +51.224998 / resolution = +51.224998 / 0.05 = 1024.49996 pixels

Now,

pixel value of the position (1,1) with respect to your map frame in x:

1024.49996 pixels + (1/resolution) = 1024.49996 pixels + (1/0.05) = 1044.49996 pixels

pixel value of the position (1,1) with respect to your map frame in y:

1024.49996 pixels + (1/resolution) = 1024.49996 pixels + (1/0.05) = 1044.49996 pixels

**Please note: I am considering the pixel values with respect to the bottom left corner of the image.**

---

Originally posted by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) with karma: 46 on 2021-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-22**:
I tried this in my code, the position of robot is somehow improved but still the robot seems to not be in exact place in given map as seen here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYn9nYN5zv8

**Comment by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) on 2021-07-22**:
hmm. that is a little weird. It looks like there is some calculation error. What are your image dimensions (in pixels) (on ubuntu, right-click on the image, go to properties > image)

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-22**:
width, height = 384*384
map.yaml:
image: ./map.pgm
resolution: 0.050000
origin: [-10.000000, -10.000000, 0.000000]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196

**Comment by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) on 2021-07-22**:
basically, if the robot pose is (x,y):
your pixel values would be (200 + x/0.05 pix, 184 - y/0.05 pix) [where your 0,0 is at the top left corner]

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-22**:
This is working, but can you tell me why 184 value is used instead of 200?

**Comment by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) on 2021-07-23**:
so (200 + x/0.05, 200 + y/0.05) is the value when you consider it with respect to the **bottom left corner** but
when you consider it with respect to the **top left corner** (which is the way in which pixels are considered for image processing), you will need to subtract image height 384 - (200+y/0.05) = 184 - y/0.05. so with respect to the top left corner, it would be  (200 + x/0.05 pix, 184 - y/0.05 pix)

**Comment by [Immanuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/78407/immanuel/) on 2021-07-23**:
Also, your application looks interesting. Are you kind of using some GUI to switch between the mapping mode and the localization mode?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-23**:
I am developing a qt quick based GUI from where user can send the mission command to any service robot deployed, here in mapping mode user can assign unique name for location selected in map.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2021-07-23**:
I am getting some trouble in getting correct location coordinated in the map from the UI, Can you tell me how do i properly convert the pixel coordinated to correct coordinate data from given map?